# Overlay coming when changing navigation bar color in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift4

I have 2 views and the navigation bar colour for View 1 is white and the navigation bar colour for view 2 is green. So when i navigate to view2 from view1 the color changes. But when i tap back the navigation bar colour changes to white and that is expected, but initially a green overlay stays on and disappears quickly.

**STEP 1 (View1)**

[image]

**STEP 2 (View2)**

[image]

**STEP 3 (*Moving to View1 from View2*)**

[image]

**then it suddenly changed to this**

[image]

Code that i am using is as follows

**For view1**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent  = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor        = UIColor(hexString: "#FFFFFF")
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let image = UIImage(named: "navBardTitleLogoBG")
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.contentMode = .center
}
```

For view2 the code is as follows

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent  = false

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor        = UIColor(hexString: "#14B80E")

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage         = UIImage()

        self.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(hexString: "#14B80E"))

        self.navigationItem.title = "Recipe Book"

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Can someone guide me how to get rid of that green overlay thats coming on while tapping the back button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the way you implement navigationBar (without seeing your code) I **assume** the way you implement UINavigationController is by manually add it from controller or by dragging navigationBar from storyboard object library instead of embed in NavigationController on your storyboard. If that is correct, you can try from your Xcode menu bar:

`Editor > Embed In > NavigationController`

It will handle the navigation and navigationBar itself.

If it's not, you can customize the size of your navigationBar/color in viewDidAppear()

I hope it answered your question.

Comment: Do you use the animate option on purpose? Have you tried to remove it?